# Can't call PowerShell script for database access (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, database, powershell, powershell-1.0

Using this database connection script I have found here. I have modified it and did the proper setting to let the script run but don't understand the error I am getting.

The script code is [here](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/powershell/querying-mysql-from-powershell):

```
Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $true,
  ParameterSetName = '',
  ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Query
  )

$MySQLAdminUserName = 'myName'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'myPass'
$MySQLDatabase = 'myDatabase'
$MySQLHost = 'HostingServerForMyDatabase'
$ConnectionString = server= + $MySQLHost + ;port=3306;uid= + $MySQLAdminUserName + ;pwd= + $MySQLAdminPassword + ;database=+$MySQLDatabase+

Try {
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]LoadWithPartialName(MySql.Data)
  $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
  $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
  $Connection.Open()

  $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
  $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, data)
  $DataSet.Tables[0]
  }

Catch {
  Write-Host ERROR  Unable to run query  $query `n$Error[0]
 }

Finally {
  $Connection.Close()
  }
```

And so, this is the error I recieve with the following command -

COMMAND: **.\MySQL.ps1 -Query "select GUID FROM MYTABLE"**

ERROR:**Parameter declerations are a comma-serperated list of variable names with optional initializer expressions. At (my script file path)\MySQL.ps1:5 char:30 + ValueFromPipeline = $true)] <<<<**

Comment: You haven't copypasted the same script as what's being linked. Double-check the content. The `$ConnectionString` is broken both on your version and on the original.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the error is not from running the script as in shown in the question nor in the link, but some unknown other script.

The error message shows you are missing the closing parentheses.

> Parameter declerations are a comma-serperated list of variable names
>   with optional initializer expressions. At (my script file
>   path)\MySQL.ps1:5 char:30 + ValueFromPipeline = **$true>]** <<<<

The code you posted here and in the link does have it correct.

```
Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $true,
  ParameterSetName = '',
  ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Query
  )
```

Notice **$true)]**

Correct MySQL.ps1 so it is exactly the same as in your link.

Comment: that was a typo I'll edit my post for that. It is correct in there, that is not the cause.

Comment: @kev2316 The updated script still has the `$ConnectionString` part broken. Please copy and paste the whole script instead of typing it in. This way you'll avoid typos.

Comment: I wasn't able to copy from the console... that's why I typed it out.

Comment: @kevin2316: Please copy from the console and your script. Otherwise your question does not make sense